# add a delay(synchronous) working with modern browsers except IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, settimeout, q

Working code: in Chrome, Firefox

```
let sleep = function (ms) {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
};
```

And somewhere in my function i use async,await to make the delay synchronous

```
function updateHandler(newTags, tagName, contentIds) {
    let deferred = Q.defer(),
        counter = 0,
        failedIDS = [],
        data = {};
    data["contentIds"] = contentIds;
    data["failedIDS"] = failedIDS;
    if (contentIds.length === 0) {
        return Promise.resolve(data);
    }
     //aync and await is here
    _.forEach(contentIds, async function (contentId) {
        //wait for some time and continue
        await sleep(150);

        let tags = [], activity;

        //API hits..
        osapi.jive.core.get({
            v: "v3",
            href: "/contents/" + contentId + ""
        }).execute(function (content) {
            tags = content.tags;
            activity = content["updated"];
            content["tags"] = _.union(tags, newTags);
            osapi.jive.core.put({
                v: "v3",
                href: "/contents/" + contentId + "",
                body: content,
                "minor": "true",
                "updated": activity
            }).execute(function (response) {
                    counter++;
                    if (response.error) {
                        failedIDS.push(contentId);
                    }
                    if (counter === contentIds.length) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    counter++;
                    failedIDS.push(contentId);
                    if (counter === contentIds.length) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }
                }
            );
        })
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

So a 0.15 seconds is must for this api hit to work and update all the items.

Since async and await won't work in IE, I wanted to write a basic `wait(ms)` function which waits for 0.15 seconds.

**Note**: So, without `sleep()` function, above loop works fine for the first iteration and fails for the second iteration and terminates the code execution. SO a must 0.15 seconds delay for each iteration is needed, this is the product limitation.

`setTimeout()` is asynchronous.. so i didn't use it.

Below code works for me.. But it's not what I want, because the browser runs out of memory and more CPU utilization, expensive..

```
function wait(ms) {
  console.log("started............");
    var start = Date.now(),
        now = start;
    while (now - start < ms) {
      now = Date.now();
    }
  console.log("finished............");
}
```

***Question:*** I want to have atleast 0.15 seconds delay for each iteration, how can I achieve it.

++ I tried the following way, picture here. Successfully updates only 16 to 19 contents, out of 100 iterable items and then throws the same `error` as it does when without `sleep()` function.
[image]

Comment: Why not just using setTimeout with your further code in the callback?

Comment: I tried that, if the iterable items are 100 then it updates for range 16 to 19 and then throws the same error( which i used to get when running without `sleep()` )

Comment: What about defining an array with your items and then setting a timeout to a function in which the first item will be passed to your api. After that the function would set another timeout to itself

Comment: Shouldn't the server notify you when it's done and ready for another operation. Waiting 150ms doesn't seem safe to me, I might be wrong though...

Comment: @moronator I thought of that idea but I had a promise resolving my success IDs. So I thought it will be a mess of promises.. and need to write promise.all()...  I am I wrong ?

Comment: @JonasGrumann : yes.. true. Even I am not happy with this workaround.. I reported this BUG with our product team.. But our management are desperate and asked me to implement a workaround. And this is the reason me being implementing this.. :(

Comment: You could switch to events, then you could trigger the events from your repetitive function when it receives a success id from the server and you could subscribe to these events where you need it

Comment: @moronator : this looks interesting, possibly firing events and subscribing them.. can you help me with an example please..

Comment: @gopigorantala You may read [this mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: Have you tried a recursive setTimeout? It should guarantee a delay between each subsequent requests

Comment: @DerekNguyen, I never tried that. how will that guarantee a delay ?

Comment: @JonasGrumann, I am doing the same in my code. I get a success, resolve it and then i increase the counter, go to the next item and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say I need to run this request function every 150ms:

```
const request = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => { console.log('done'); res() }, 1000))
//
```

Then I can use `setTimeout` recursively to add a delay between each request:

```
let counter = 0;

// this handler will be passed into a setTimeout
// to kick off the whole thing
const handler = () => {
  console.log(counter);

  // request api thing
  request().then(() => {
    counter++;
    if (counter === 100) return;
    setTimeout(handler, 150) // remove this
  })
}

// kick off
setTimeout(handler, 150)
```

It makes sure each request is finished before waiting to run the next one.

Comment: I have a recursive function call ex: `updateHandler(a,b,c).then(...)` and in `then()` I check if check for failedIds.. and if they `!=0` then call the same recursive fn. Let me try your approach within the iteration and resolve the promise..

Comment: Thank you.. this solution worked for me.. though I need to make the promise compatible to IE

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.5/bluebird.min.js"></script>` adding this made the Promise work like a charm..

Comment: glad it helps. I had to develop for ie11 a few times in the past and [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io) is a god-send!

Comment: since each `promise` is resolved.. I made the timeout's to 0 instead of 150millis.. its more optimised with performance.. beware placing 0 also adds some delay to `setTimeout` for 16 to 20millis..  ref:[event-loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)  (awesomely explained..).. watch this video till the end, it will make more sense how event loop works in a single threaded environment(JS).